# foreach loop array sql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to select values from my database when the value != 0 but all I get is an empty array.

Here I've got an array with all the names who are also in the database.

```
$array  = ['helm' , 'weapon', 'amulet', 'body', 'legs', "boots", 'shield', 'gloves', 'cape'];
```

then I place the array in a foreach loop and place the `_name` and `_value` behind the name (in the database it is `helm_name = blabla` `_helm value = 10` )

When the text is placed behind the word I loop through it in my `query` in which I try to select the `name table (for example helm_name`) and the `value table (for example helm_value)`

```
foreach($array as $array_item){
    $array_item_name = $array_item.'_name';
    $array_item_value = $array_item.'_value';

    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT ".$array_item_name." FROM player WHERE naam = :naam AND ".$array_item_value." != 0");
    $sql->execute(array(":naam" => $naam));
    $fetch = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

but all it returns when I run it is `Array ( )`  what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the database error value, also you should create the sql string first and output it, so that you could manually run the generated sql statement.

Comment: Check the database error value? andcreate the sql string first like `$sql = "SELECT ".$array_item_name." FROM player WHERE naam = :naam AND ".$array_item_value." != 0";` and then `$sql = $db->prepare($sql)`?

Comment: Exactly thats simple debug technique ;-)

Comment: But how do I prevent it from returning and empty array? Because when I echo the $sql it returns `SELECT helm_name FROM player WHERE naam = :naam AND helm_value != 0`  (for every item in the array, so helm / weapon etcetc) which is correct but still returns an empty array while there are plenty of columns with a `value` above 0

Comment: After the execute do you have checked the number of result values from the execute? If so, do you have done an print_r($fetch);  ?

Comment: I know what I did wrong. I had the `print_r($fetch)` outside of the `for loop` but now I want to get the results by name. But I tried putting the `results` from the sql in a new array ` $results[] = $fetch;` and `print` it outside of the for loop but the result is `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [helm_name] => a warriors helmet ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [weapon_name] => a bone ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [amulet_name] => a golden necklace ) ) [3] => Array ( ) [4] => Array ( ) [5] => Array ( ) [6] => Array ( ) [7] => Array ( ) [8] => Array ( ) )` how do I do this correctly?

Comment: So it will just return something like array([0] => helm_name => a warriors helmet, [1] etcetc) or something else to easily get it out of the array / sql result

Comment: Please specifiy what you expect.

Comment: I want to create 1 array with all values in it. Instead of all little arrays in 1 array. I know the for loop causes it but I cant get it out of the database without it(I think?)

Comment: How do you mean? Do you have an example..?

Comment: It would be better to use the loop(s) only for creating the statement and then having all results in one array. So you need a loop for creating a naam in (...) butting in all naam values separated by ",". Question is why you are avoiding the 0 values? would be simpler if you get 0 values also from the db.